TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable when executing scipy.io.loadmat() after importing a module
I have a notebook main.ipynb and a module data.py.
In data.py, there is:
import scipy
mousedata = scipy.io.loadmat("../datafiles/C57_913_Qiu/time_binned_DiscreteSpikes.mat")

In main.ipynb I imported:
import numpy as np
import scipy
import sys

The first cell:
mousedata = scipy.io.loadmat("../datafiles/C57_913_Qiu/time_binned_DiscreteSpikes.mat")

The second cell:
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../library'))
import data as d

The third cell:
mousedata = scipy.io.loadmat("../datafiles/C57_913_Qiu/time_binned_DiscreteSpikes.mat")

Supposedly the first cell and the third cell should do the same thing. However, if I execute the third cell after the second cell, it will produce the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 1
----> 1 mousedatatest = t.load_data("../datafiles/C57_913_Qiu/time_binned_DiscreteSpikes.mat")

File ~/code/bayesian_decoder/scripts/testing.py:5, in load_data(filepath)
      3 def load_data(filepath):
      4     print(f"Loading data from: {filepath}")
----> 5     return scipy.io.loadmat(filepath)

File /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/_mio.py:226, in loadmat(file_name, mdict, appendmat, **kwargs)
    224 variable_names = kwargs.pop('variable_names', None)
    225 with _open_file_context(file_name, appendmat) as f:
--> 226     MR, _ = mat_reader_factory(f, **kwargs)
    227     matfile_dict = MR.get_variables(variable_names)
    229 if mdict is not None:

File /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/_mio.py:74, in mat_reader_factory(file_name, appendmat, **kwargs)
     54 """
     55 Create reader for matlab .mat format files.
     56 
   (...)
     71 
     72 """
     73 byte_stream, file_opened = _open_file(file_name, appendmat)
---> 74 mjv, mnv = _get_matfile_version(byte_stream)
     75 if mjv == 0:
     76     return MatFile4Reader(byte_stream, **kwargs), file_opened

File /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/_miobase.py:233, in _get_matfile_version(fileobj)
    231 if len(mopt_bytes) == 0:
    232     raise MatReadError("Mat file appears to be empty")
--> 233 mopt_ints = np.ndarray(shape=(4,), dtype=np.uint8, buffer=mopt_bytes)
    234 if 0 in mopt_ints:
    235     fileobj.seek(0)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

How can I resolve this error?
The above problem was a simplified version of the issue I encountered. The original problem was when I import data.py which has:
def load_matfiles(file_path):
    """
    Load files with either scipy.io.loadmat or mat73.loadmat.
    """
    try:
        # Attempt to load the .mat file using scipy
        data = scipy.io.loadmat(file_path)
        print(file_path, "loaded with scipy.io.loadmat")
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"scipy.io.loadmat failed: {e})")
        print("Trying mat73.loadmat...")
        try:
            # Attempt to load the .mat file using mat73
            data = mat73.loadmat(file_path)
            print(file_path, "loaded with mat73.loadmat")
            return data
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"mat73.loadmat also failed: {e}")
            raise


def load_data(mouse_ID):
    """
    Load necessary data files of the selected mouse:
    - time_binned_SpikeInf
    - time_binned_DiscreteSpikes
    - target_positions
    - darktrial_raw
    - del_trials
    """
    time_binned_SpikeInf = load_matfiles("../datafiles/"+ mouse_ID +"/time_binned_SpikeInf.mat")
    time_binned_DiscreteSpikes = load_matfiles("../datafiles/"+ mouse_ID +"/time_binned_DiscreteSpikes.mat")
    target_positions = load_matfiles("../datafiles/"+ mouse_ID +"/target_positions.mat")
    darktrial_raw = load_matfiles("../datafiles/"+ mouse_ID +"/darktrial_raw.mat")
    del_trials = load_matfiles("../datafiles/"+ mouse_ID +"/del_trials.mat")

    return time_binned_SpikeInf, time_binned_DiscreteSpikes, target_positions, darktrial_raw, del_trials

I tried to simplify the data.py as in above. I have also checked scipy version = 1.13.1. My python version is 3.12.4. I have tried uninstalling scipy and reinstalling. I have tried installing it to an older version = 1.11.

What other files are in the directory ../library ? In particular, is there a file named numpy.py in it? That could cause the issue you mention.

After the import see if numpy/np still works. Some how np.ndarray has changed to the None` object.

@NickODell the other files are utils.py, preprocess.py. So I don't think that's the issue.
@hpaulj This seems to be the issue. I tried creating a np.ndarray after import and it doesn't work, giving the same error. But other functions like np.sum works

Check other np properties, like __version__ and __file.
